# Trouble Extracting Review from Yelp

Tags: python, web-scraping, pycharm

Started web **scraping** and I've been trying to get the rating off this yelp review.

my code:

```
rating = review.find('img', attrs={'class': 'offscreen__373c0__1KofL'}).get('alt')

rating = float(re.findall('\d+', rating)[0])

print(rating)
```

result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/joseochoa/PycharmProjects/webbscraper/Tutorial_scraper.py", line 40, in <module>
    rating = float(re.findall('\d+', rating)[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: FYI what you're doing is __scraping__, not scrapping. Scrapping means throwing away like rubbish.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `re.findall('\d+', rating)` returns empty list. 
For this reason when you try to get the first element of the list you have this error.

You can modify your code like this:

```
rating = review.find('img', attrs={'class': 'offscreen__373c0__1KofL'}).get('alt')
rating_list = re.findall('\d+', rating)

if len(rating_list) > 0:
   rating_float = float(rating_list[0])
   print(rating_float)
else:
   print("No matches have been found")
   # manage with specific actions if you want
```